# powershell combine lync and AD cmdlets

Tags: powershell

I'm trying to write a single command in PS which lets me the AD account for all lync enabled users by samaccountname

I tried this:

```
get-csuser | where {$_.Enabled -eq $True -and $_.SipAddress -ne $null} | foreach-object {get-aduser -filter {samaccountname -eq $_.samaccountname}}
```

This however doesn't work

I know I can do this with a simple script, but the reason I need to do this on the command line is that I am using C# to invoke the above, and I don't want to create 2 powershell objects (for performance reason), so I would like to run the entire command in one powershell unit.

Any ideas how should I fix the above script?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right, here I am answering my own question again (rather than deleting my post, incase it helps someone in the future).

It seems the property name is case-sensitive, so I need to replace:

> $_.samaacountname

with

> $_.SamAccountName

works like a charm after that

Answer (score 0):

get-csuser | select samaccountname

Comment: that's a little brief